# Is saying "This was the best part of an otherwise incredible day!" a correct usage of 'otherwise'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm asking because I saw this tweet: https://twitter.com/chrissyteigen/status/910404003736854528, (""Otherwise" implies you did not like hangin with this baby."), which is criticizing the usage of the word "otherwise" in Ivanka Trump's tweet which reads "Cuddling my little nephew Luke... the best part of an otherwise incredible day!"

The way 'otherwise' is used there makes it sound like the cuddling with the baby part was not 'incredible' like the rest of the day, thus contradicting that it was the 'best part', but I'm not sure if it is actually technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps less than ideal.

The audience can do the math on it and know that since it is differentiating *best* with *incredible* that the *otherwise* isn't contrasting opposites but things that differ only by degree.

And that's perfectly sensible and valid.

That *otherwise* is more often used for things that are actually opposed, and since it's redundant ("the best part of an incredible day" works just as well, indeed better) means the sentence would likely have been better writing without it, but it's not wrong.